# How to convert and compare a date string post value with a createcritera filed date in grails?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, grails-orm, createcriteria

I use Grails 2.0.3 
and am comparing a a date string post value using creatCriteria and i have used below methods to convert the string into date but it always empty ? when i try , i can use params.date() method since i pass only one string ,for searching it can be date in one time ,or it can be number and so on ...

```
 println Date.parse('2013-02-05')
```

my creatCriteria

```
 def vDate = new Date().parse(query.toString())

   {

  eq('dateCreated',vDate) 

   }
```

what am missing or any alternative ? i still believe that this trivial issue has to be resolved enough for future use?

Comment: FYI you can do this: `params.date("yourField", "yyyy-MM-dd")`. You can also use HQL and `trunc()` the date on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all convert your String to date using this method.

```
def date = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd','2013-02-05')
```

Now use today start and today end method.

```
Date getTodayStart( Date inDate){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.set(inDate[Calendar.YEAR], inDate[Calendar.MONTH], inDate[Calendar.DATE], 0, 0, 0)
    Date todayStart = cal.getTime()

    return todayStart
}

Date getTodayEnd(Date inDate){
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.set(inDate[Calendar.YEAR], inDate[Calendar.MONTH], inDate[Calendar.DATE], 0, 0, -1)
    Date todayEnd = cal.getTime() + 1

    return todayEnd
}
```

It will give you object from day start to day end.

```
Date startDate = getTodayStart(date)
Date endDate =  getTodayEnd(date)
```

Now you can create criteria for date.

```
  {
  between('dateCreated',startDate.toString(),endDate.toString()) 
  }
```

It will give you all date for that day.

Comment: Is this helpfull for you or not?

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Date vDate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(query.toString())
```

Comment: newdate = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2013-  05-24")
println "NEW DATE TOP "+ newdate

Comment: the above doesn't work returntinf the perfect formatt i expect date value of 2013-05-24 ,but it rather display  "NEW DATE TOP Fri May 24 00:00:00 EAT 2013"

Comment: earlier you said that you want to parse date in order to use it criteria, right? then using my code you can get a Date object, if you print it it uses toString() method which produces date in that format, you can use SimpleDateFormat class again for formatiing it to yyyy-MM-dd format if you want, see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Yes Se Dude it works fine my bad , tricked by to string methods actually it works with the database comparison too! thanks@

Answer (score 1):

If your database column is of type `Date` then you should not have problem using the way @Kamil has suggested. Although, there is a groovier way of parsing the date string to date.

```
def date = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd','2013-02-05')
assert date instanceof java.util.Date
```

Comment: Glad it was of help. Accepting an appropriate answer will add more to the appreciation. :)